# Is it possible to see what languages the app supports during run time

Tags: android, locale

Is it possible to check what languages that my app supports during run time?

ie  what string file exist in the app for each locale.

The following command is the opposite - it shows what languages the phone supports.

```
Locale[] locs= Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

Comment: What is the definition of "what languages that my app supports"? Bear in mind that most likely you are using libraries, which have their own strings with their own translations.

Comment: I want to let the user input a language during run time and then I want the app to change to that language by using string files for each locale, however I do not have a string file for every language so i want to check once the user enters a language if said language is supported

Comment: That does not answer my question. What is the definition of "what languages that my app supports"? Do you really mean "the languages for which I have a translation of this specific string"? Do you really mean "the languages for which I have a translation of any string, including those coming from libraries created by Google and others"? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I'd advise against this feature.  If the user wants to change languages, they can change the locale on the device.  Anything else is going to be fighting the built in system and lead to months of bugs.

Comment: @Gabe the problem is, is that I am supporting languages that the phone doesn't support and our website does, so if the user changes the language on the website i need to change the language on the phone.  (if android supported all the languages that my app supports this would be a non issue).  However if the user changes to a language in the website that the app doesnt support i would prefer to default back to the phone language.

Comment: CommonsWare, currently I am not using any libraries for languages however I want to make a pull request to return this as a contribution to the open source project my app is a fork of so the more support i give the better

Comment: @AdamKatz WHy would the language of your website effect the language of an app on the phone?  There's no reason the two should be tied.  As I said-  you will spend months fighting the ANdroid OS to do this-  months that would be better spent providing actual value to your users.  If you are going to do this-  don't use any of the built in android locale functionality.  The only way to do this right is to completely replace the entire strings subsystem.

Comment: I have already implemented this part of it and it at least appears to be working fine (only took me 2 days so maybe i am missing possible bugs?).  The only problem i am facing is that I cannot tell what languages the app supports.  

The reason is as i said, some user of my app live in countries with languages that android doesnt support in the app and since they are using our website they would like to use the app in the same language.

Comment: "currently I am not using any libraries for languages" -- I am not referring to libraries *for languages*. I am referring to *libraries in general*. If you have libraries listed in the `dependencies` closure in your module's `build.gradle` file, those libraries may contain their own strings, with their own set of translations, in whatever languages the library developers elected to support. In the case of many Google libraries (e.g., Play Services SDK), the library will support a *lot* of languages.

Comment: Ahh good point.  So what I want is which languages my app supports in the String's file